# free GLUtils.texImage2D

Tags: android, opengl-es

The source is this:

```
 public static int loadTexture ( Bitmap bitmap )
{
    //long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] textureId = new int[1];

    GLES20.glGenTextures ( 1, textureId, 0 );
    GLES20.glBindTexture ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId[0] );

    GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
    GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR );
    GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
    GLES20.glTexParameteri ( GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    try{
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return textureId[0];
}
```

I want to recycle the bitmap int the method GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0) and free the memory,please help me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the texture from OpenGL, use:

```
GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, textureId, 0);
```

to free the bitmap itself, use:

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

You can recycle the bitmap once it has been loaded into OpenGL.

Comment: I consider when call GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0); the bitmap is copy the pixes array to the OPEN GL render cache.Because I call the method bitmap after the  loadTexture ( Bitmap bitmap ).

Comment: Whether on call GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, textureId, 0) the OPEN GL should free the cache of texture buffer with textureId?